# Post request to another URL from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, url, post, request

I want to create a page in ASP.NET which will, send request to another non ASP.NET URL, and check something there, in my case it is to check, is the domain name free, or it is already in use. (Method = POST) As a result i want to get an HTML code, from which i will extract a result, using RegEx. The last part, I can do myself :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to send a POST request and fetch the contents of a remote resource:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "param1", "value 1" },
        { "param2", "value 2" },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/foo", values);
    // TODO: process the results
}
```

> from which i will extract a result, using RegEx. The last part, I can do myself :)

I hope you are aware about the general opinion on [parsing HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). So even if you can do this yourself, **don't do it**. Use a HTML parser such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to process the results.

Comment: Thank You.
Sorry for stupid question, but i don't understand where can i specify the URL to which i post ? 
client.UploadValues("http://my.url", values); ???

Comment: @Armen Sarkisian, yes, you specify it as first argument of the `UploadValues` method.

Comment: @Armen Sarkisian, if this post helped you solve the problem please [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

My final code looks like this. As you said `RegEx` did not work, and i used simple `IndexOf`.

```
        string domain = tb_domain.Text;
        string level = ddl_level.SelectedValue;
        string html = "";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "whois_search", domain },
                { "domainEnd", level  },
            };


            byte[] res = client.UploadValues("http://registration.ge/index.php?page=11&lang=geo", values);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(res[i]);
                char c = Convert.ToChar(a);
                html += Convert.ToString(c);
            }

            int ind = html.IndexOf("Registrant");

            if (ind == -1)
            {
                lbl_result.Text = "The domain is free, you can register it";
                lbl_result.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_result.Text = "The Domain is used";
                lbl_result.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
```